# phpstan array shape definition using a class constant

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpstan

Is there a way to use class constants to define array shapes in phpstan?

The purpose is to enable the definition to be used by PHP code, otherwise we have to repeat the definition (once for phpstan and once for PHP) and that feels wrong!

For example, we have:

```
/**
 * @phpstan-type BarArrayShape = array{
 *     abc => string,
 *     def => string,
 *     ghi => int,
 *     jkl => \DateTime,
 * }
 */
class Foo
{
    private const ARRAY_SHAPE_BAR = [
        'abc' => 'string',
        'def' => 'string',
        'ghi' => 'int',
        'jkl' => '\DateTime',
    ];

    /**
     * @param BarArrayShape $dataArray
     * @return void
     */
    public function doSomething(array $bar): void
    {
        $expectedKeys = array_keys(self::ARRAY_SHAPE_BAR);
        foreach ($expectedKeys as $key) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

We used to use PHP Storm ArrayShape attributes (which worked fine) but trying to migrate to phpstan instead.

E.g. used to be able to do something like this:

```
    public function doSomething(#[ArrayShape(self::ARRAY_SHAPE_BAR)] array $bar) {}
```

Is there a way to do the same in phpstan?

I've tried doing:

@phpstan-type BarArrayShape = self::ARRAY_SHAPE_BAR. It works for the array keys, but the syntax is wrong, so it thinks that 'int' is a literal string which says 'int', and not an integer type definition.

Is there a solution?